# Create three "sections" for information

Tags: html, css, flat

I have trouble finding out how to make something close to this.
I had a very hard time trying to find a way to make this, first using google, and then using the javascript console to read html and css.. But websites have such more advanced coding than it seems they should have.. This is what i want to recreate

http://conversionlab.no/ (Scroll down until you see the three flat icons with text and a description under them

Comment: Then you need to hire a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to learn Bootstrap for this, though it's not mandatory. In Bootstrap you could just define it like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">Content 1</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Content 2</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Content 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

A basic way to do this without Bootstrap is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zs9f/1/